# Display Unicode character in MFC Static Text

Tags: unicode, mfc

I am trying to get an MFC Static Text control to display an <del>ASCII</del> Unicode character, specifically Omega (`&#937`).  When i use just that the `&` doesn't display and the rest of the text does. But if i set the 'No Prefix' Property of the Control to True, then it removes the `&` and everything after it.

Is this possible to do through a project setting or am i just inputting the string wrong?

Here is what I am using for a string: `VDC Resistance (k&#937)` → where I want `&#937` to be the omega symbol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all `&#937` isn't an ASCII character, it is a Unicode character: [GREEK CAPITAL LETTER OMEGA](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/3a9/index.htm).

`&#937` is the Html escape sequence for an omega, so a static text control doesn't do translate Html escape sequences.  If you are entering the text in C/C++ source then use the C escape sequence `L"\u03A9"`.  (3A9 in hex equals 937 decimal).  This assumes that you are building a Unicode application in in ANSI it won't work.  I'm not sure how you would do it in that case.

Comment: Thanks. I totally overlooked the fact i listed the HTML escape sequence. My project isn't unicode and i don't know if I will be able to make it unicode yet as my project is an add in to an already existing MFC project. Thank you for the correction and answer.